# More control over middleware ordering via Railtie?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, middleware

There are gems/libraries that would benefit from better control over where they inject their middleware.

In particular it would be nice if exception-handling middleware were at the top of the stack.

Is there any way to do this, or can it only be done by editing config.ru?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no intrinsic way to do this other than manually ordering the middleware stack. I've seen a hack where you could monkey patch Rack::Builder to provide you with some push/pop capabilities.

https://github.com/joshbuddy/rack-capabilities

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is want you need: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Configuration/MiddlewareStackProxy.html

It is possible do the following:

```
config.middleware.insert_before Rack::Head, Magical::Unicorns
config.middleware.insert_after Rack::Head, Magical::Unicorns
config.middleware.swap ActionDispatch::Flash, Magical::Unicorns
config.middleware.delete ActionDispatch::Flash
```

You can just define your Railtie and manipulate the middlewares around.